# how to print a DIV contents with A5 size and keep css using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, printthis

how to print a DIV contents with A5 size and keep css using jQuery?

am used [printThis.js](https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/) but print preview coming without CSS alignments and page size is different..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this within printThis (I'm the author), but you can use CSS.

Look at this CSS3 examples from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#size:

```
/* style sheet for "A4" printing */
@media print and (width: 21cm) and (height: 29.7cm) {
     @page {
        margin: 3cm;
     }
}

/* style sheet for "letter" printing */
@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {
    @page {
        margin: 1in;
    }
}

/* A4 Landscape*/
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 10%;
}
```

Comment: why loadCSS: "\stylesheets\print.css", not working ,nodejs express project with handlebars, am tried file path with different formats but stll not showing designed view in print preview

Comment: see my printing design is here https://i.postimg.cc/pXtKvtmW/jobsheet1.jpg  and see the print preview is here https://i.postimg.cc/7YM0YQzg/jobsheetprintpreview.jpg

why this all in left side ?

Comment: @HabeebKambrath - the path needs to be a fully qualified path, as the contents are getting written into an iframe and it needs the full path to load correctly.

Comment: are you see the image ? it's sure CSS issue ? other CSS props are coming there but some not i think , what you think ?

Comment: @HabeebKambrath If you're printing  the whole page (or most of it) you don't need my plugin. You can just use a print media query in your CSS to hide the few things you don't want printing. As for your screenshots, I can't determine the cause without seeing the code. Have you followed the instructions to debug? https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/wiki/Troubleshooting-Printing-Problems